# can I use isAssignableFrom to check C1 is a subtype of C2 in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

Here is an example:

```
class test {

static interface I<A> { }

static class Y implements I<Integer> { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
  // this is not allowed by the compiler:
  //I<String> s = new Y() ;
  // yet:   
  System.out.println(">" + I.class.isAssignableFrom(Y.class)) ; // true!        
}
}
```

So, I conclude that isAssignable is not always correct in its answer. Is this a correct conclusion? Is there a better way to check for subtyping at the runtime?

Thanks. --Wish.

Comment: What is your exact question? `Y` is a subtype of `I` and therefore `I` `isAssignableFrom` `Y`.

Comment: For my purpose, I mean the following: Y is a subtype of I, if any instance of Y is also an instance of I. Given any type Y and I, I need to be able to check this at the runtime.

Comment: That's what you are currently doing.

Comment: Hmm... that's also not really what I am trying to find out. "I" has type parameter, which makes it confusing. What I want is actually to have a piece of code that check wheter Y is a subtype of I<String>.

Answer (score 1):

You got tripped up by *type erasure*. The `isAssignableFrom` method operates on the erased (raw) type `I`. The compiler, on the other hand sees you try to assign a `I<Integer>` to an `I<String>`, and disallows the assignment.

You may be able to determine the actual implemented type via [getGenericInterfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces%28%29) et. al. Then you can check for the returned type being an instance of `ParamterizedType`, and get the actual type bound.

Usually, this is very rarely necessary, though.

Comment: I see. Well.. there is also this "Type" things in Java, which does give me full information. See:  
file:///C:/apps/Java/jdk1.8.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html


Is the an analogous of isAssignableFrom that operates on Type instead?

Comment: @user3501141 No, but `Type` can often be cast to something from which you can obtain a raw class and do an assignable check on that.